# Vb.NET how to pack .DLL to app and copy it to any folder (like patcher or cracker app)

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to make an application similar to patcher and cracker app with vb.net?
I don't want to people see my secret .dll that I copied and replace the old one, so it should be one .exe app

Sorry for my bad English :)
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at ILMerge: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630

Comment: Can I make this, exe1.exe + exe.dll, merge to exe2.exe, so when I run exe2.exe it will run exe1.exe inside and do copy with exe.dll inside exe2.exe?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a single EXE that includes 1 or more DLLs that are not used by the EXE but are information which you can use to write the actual DLL to the hard drive.

I have done this before, dont know if someone else has a better way but you can try this:

Create a new program that will read the DLL into a byte array, then convert this byte array into a string by creating a function that will convert each byte into a string representation. (might be some other way to do that but I did this because the DLL is binary and if you just try to decode it, it will fail when you try to reverse this process below) Then make the file that you output as a resource of your EXE.

Now, in your EXE, you will do just the reverse and end up writing your DLL to the hard drive.

BTW, with mine, I compressed the byte array to help with space but it is not required.  Maybe you can include that in a future release.

Comment: can you show me how to convert dll to byte to string and reverse it? I have  no idea to do that, there are still many thing I must learn from you and another people here . . .

Comment: See other answer for example. Impossible to put that much code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

How to convert binary byte array to string and back. The example works specifically with a JPG image but you should be able to convert it with a little work to a DLL/File.

```
Private Function BitmapToString(ByVal BM As Image) As String
    Dim MS As New IO.MemoryStream
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    BM.Save(MS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()

    Dim ba As Byte() = MS.ToArray
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    'ba = CompressBytes(ba)

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder("")
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    sb.Append(ba(0))
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    For i As Integer = 1 To ba.Length - 1
        Select Case ba(i).ToString.Length
            Case 1
                sb.Append("  " & ba(i))
            Case 2
                sb.Append(" " & ba(i))
            Case 3
                sb.Append(ba(i))
            Case Else
                Stop
        End Select
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Next
    Return sb.ToString
End Function
Private Function StringToBitmap(ByVal sString As String) As Image
    Dim aList As New ArrayList

    If sString.Length Mod 3 = 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To sString.Length - 1 Step 3
            aList.Add(CByte(sString.Substring(i, 3)))
        Next
        Dim ba As Byte()
        ba = aList.ToArray(GetType(Byte))
        'ba = DecompressBytes(ba)
        Dim MS As New IO.MemoryStream(ba)

        Return New Bitmap(MS)
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

NOTE: CompressBytes() and DecompressBytes() are my own functions, you do not need them for this to work.